# How can i get the cpu information in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

like whether it is pentium or AMD etc.

Answer (score 12):

**Please note that this is from VS2003:**

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher win32Proc = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor")
{
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in win32Proc.Get())
    {
        clockSpeed = obj["CurrentClockSpeed"].ToString();
        procName = obj["Name"].ToString();
        manufacturer = obj["Manufacturer"].ToString();
        version = obj["Version"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that "CurrentClockSpeed" is not the property you should be looking at to determine MHz (Windows can clock-down most modern processors when utilization is low, so as to save energy).

Instead you should look at "MaxClockSpeed" -- which is the maximum clock speed that Windows can clock the processor at.

Answer (score 3):

The [System.Management Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx)
Provides access to a rich set of management information and management events about the system, devices, and applications instrumented to the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) infrastructure.

The [Win32 Processor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(VS.85).aspx) WMI class represents a device that can interpret a sequence of instructions on a computer running on a Windows operating system. On a multiprocessor computer, one instance of the Win32_Processor class exists for each processor. The class includes a `Processor family type` field, encoding things like *AMD Opteron Processor Family*.

An example of [C# issuing WMI query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) is at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

**This code will get CPU properties**

```
Imports System.Management



    Private Sub InsertInfo()
                lstView.Items.Clear()

                Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Processor")

                Try
                    For Each share As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()

                        Dim grp As ListViewGroup
                        Try
                            grp = lstView.Groups.Add(share("Name").ToString(), share("Name").ToString())
                        Catch
                            grp = lstView.Groups.Add(share.ToString(), share.ToString())
                        End Try

                        If share.Properties.Count <= 0 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("No Information Available", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                            Return
                        End If


                        For Each PC As PropertyData In share.Properties

                            Dim item As New ListViewItem(grp)
                            If lstView.Items.Count Mod 2 <> 0 Then
                                item.BackColor = Color.White
                            Else
                                item.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
                            End If

                            item.Text = PC.Name

                            If PC.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso PC.Value.ToString().Length > 0 Then
                                Select Case PC.Value.GetType().ToString()
                                    Case "System.String[]"
                                        Dim str As String() = DirectCast(PC.Value, String())

                                        Dim str2 As String = ""
                                        For Each st As String In str
                                            str2 += st & " "
                                        Next

                                        item.SubItems.Add(str2)

                                        Exit Select
                                    Case "System.UInt16[]"
                                        Dim shortData As UShort() = DirectCast(PC.Value, UShort())


                                        Dim tstr2 As String = ""
                                        For Each st As UShort In shortData
                                            tstr2 += st.ToString() & " "
                                        Next

                                        item.SubItems.Add(tstr2)

                                        Exit Select
                                    Case Else

                                        item.SubItems.Add(PC.Value.ToString())
                                        Exit Select
                                End Select
                            Else
                                Continue For
                            End If
                            lstView.Items.Add(item)
                        Next
                    Next


                Catch exp As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show("can't get data because of the followeing error " & vbLf & exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                End Try


                End Sub
```